# Javascript works after page refresh, not knowing the solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, refresh

I have these two very easy javascript in custom.js file.

and the problem is that it works only after page refresh.

Now it is in the **body** tag. Where should I put? How can I solve to make it work normally (not to refresh the site manually). I tried (document).ready but still not works.

My **HTML**

```
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://nosolution.com/js/custom.js"></script>

<span class="underline">Text</span>
<button>Change</button>

<span class="underline">Text</span>
<button class="hid">Change</button>
```

My **javascript**

```
   $(document).on('pageinit',function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
         $("span.underline").addClass("underlined");
      });

     $("button.hid").click(function(){
        $("span.underline").removeClass("underlined");
     });
});
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest using `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).on('pageinit',`. Also, you don't need two `$(document).on('pageinit'`. One will do just fine.

Comment: Thank you for voting down my question! That means it has no solution! The document.ready function is also not working as I said before!

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. Don't take it so personally. Your code is poorly indented, you don't show the HTML that you're loading it in and your wording is ambiguous. This makes it a difficult question to answer and not a very good resource in the future. That's why someone downvoted your question.

Comment: I read about that its loaded faster, and maybe a page / or cache reload should solve somehow, but seems no solution just -1

Comment: Like I said. Show us your HTML. Look in your console (hit F12) for any errors. The code you posted is just fine, if a bit unconventional.

Comment: How are you loading your Javascript? None of that HTML contains any `<script>` tags.

Comment: try this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/uwsutrz7/1/

Comment: Its the same! My problem is as I said that this works only after I reload the page with f5 or clicking on the refresh button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
        $("span.underline").addClass("underlined");
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'button.hid', function(){
        $("span.underline").removeClass("underlined");
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately its not working.

Comment: WOW! Thanks, thats working, but not perfectly but its working. Thank you very much!, I started to think about solving this issue with getScript but now its good. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Mike C. is correct.  Your code should be formed as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("span.underline").addClass("underlined");
    });

    $("button.hid").click(function(){
        $("span.underline").removeClass("underlined");
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried this.Not working Thanks. Needs the refresh, to work.